# Highlighting a row in SE site list table also selects older sites, regardless of sort

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com

When visiting https://stackexchange.com/sites#lifearts-traffic I scrolled down so that Writers.SE was near the top, did a mousedown just a bit above and to the left of the Writers logo, then dragged down and right to highlight the Writers row in that table (then used CTRL+C to Copy).

To my great surprise, I found that (a) Personal Finance and Money, Photography, Home Improvement, and Seasoned Advice (various apparently-randomly selected sites above it in the list) were also selected, and (b) I could not get my selection of that row to include the Twitter link.

I eventually figured out that the other ones being highlighted were the *older* sites in the list, but this doesn't make much sense from the user perspective because the sites are sorted by traffic by default and that's indicated in the URL, the drop-down options, and has been the consistent sort (i.e. I hadn't started viewing by Oldest and then just changed something on the page).  This is very unexpected behavior from the user perspective.